# Nim Slack bot Signature Verification Issues

Tags: slack, nim-lang

I'm fairly new to Nim, and I suspect I'm just doing something wrong here. I'm using Jester (for routing, etc) and Nimcrytpo (for hmac) but something isn't adding up. Here's how I'm attempting to verify a signature:

```
import jester
import dotenv
import os, strutils, times
import nimcrypto

const timestampHeader = "X-Slack-Request-Timestamp"
const slackSignatureHeader = "X-Slack-Signature"
const signatureVersion = "v0"
const signingSecret = os.getEnv("SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET")

proc isTimestampRecent(timestamp: int): bool =
  abs(getTime().toUnix - timestamp) <= (60 * 5)

proc verifySignature*(request: Request): bool =
  if (not request.headers.hasKey timestampHeader) or
  (not request.headers.hasKey slackSignatureHeader):
    return false

  let timestamp = request.headers[timestampHeader].parseInt
  if not timestamp.isTimestampRecent():
    return false

  let baseString = signatureVersion & ':' & $timestamp & ':' & $request.body
  let mySignature = sha256.hmac(signingSecret, baseString)

  let slackSignature = MDigest[256].fromHex(request.headers[slackSignatureHeader])

  mySignature == slackSignature
```

A few things I'm running into:

1. The signature doesn't match, and I'm not really sure how to debug that. I'm definitely getting a valid request from Slack and following the instructions for verification here: https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack#about, but it's incorrect.
2. I know I'm missing the `v0=` in the comparison, but I'm not quite sure how to do that with the time independent comparison (whether I should be skipping that part or not in the comparison, etc)

My best guess at this point is that somehow the Jester/Httpbeast request body isn't "raw" enough (though it's just plain json...?) or is somehow processed.

Any help or suggestions on how to debug would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would try and reproduce step by step the example provided at the slack link

Comment: @pietroppeter, thanks, I had been getting too caught in the weeds. When I debugged step by step I found several things!

Comment: you are welcome, if you happen to solve the problem you can post your solution here (and after a delay you can approve it as correct answer), so that others can learn from it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fussing with this for a while, I found I was doing a number of things incorrectly! Hopefully this helps others:

1. The `signingSecret` is pulled from the env, so it shouldn't be a constant--I moved that into the proc itself defined with `let` instead.
2. The slack signature in the headers is prefixed with `v0=`, which makes it the wrong length for `MDigest[256].fromHex()`, so that was ending up as the null value (`0000...`) instead of what should've been.

Here's a working version, now in case anyone else should need one. Please let me know if you see anything that could be improved as well.

```
import jester
import dotenv
import os, strutils, times
import nimcrypto

const timestampHeader = "X-Slack-Request-Timestamp"
const slackSignatureHeader = "X-Slack-Signature"
const signatureVersion = "v0"

proc isTimestampRecent(timestamp: int): bool =
  abs(getTime().toUnix - timestamp) <= (60 * 5)

proc verifySignature*(request: Request): bool =
  let signingSecret = os.getEnv("SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET")

  if (not request.headers.hasKey timestampHeader) or
  (not request.headers.hasKey slackSignatureHeader):
    return false

  let timestamp = request.headers[timestampHeader].parseInt
  if not timestamp.isTimestampRecent():
    return false

  let baseString = signatureVersion & ':' & $timestamp & ':' & $request.body
  let mySignature = sha256.hmac(signingSecret, baseString)

  var rawSlackSignature: string = $request.headers[slackSignatureHeader]
  rawSlackSignature.removePrefix(signatureVersion & '=')

  let slackSignature = MDigest[256].fromHex(rawSlackSignature)

  mySignature == slackSignature
```